# Intellij SpringBoot Maven Dependency problems

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am new to Maven and SpringBoot. I am trying to run a Maven SpringBoot project in Intellij but, the dependencies are not getting resolved. I have tried all the things I could find but they did not work. Below is my POM.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <groupId>com.optum.csp-claims</groupId>
    <artifactId>claims-benefit-period-post</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
    <name>claims-benefit-period-post</name>
    <description>Post process for Claims benefit period calc</description>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <slf4j.slf4j-simple.version>1.6.2</slf4j.slf4j-simple.version>
        <oracle.jdbc.version>12.2.0.1</oracle.jdbc.version>
        <squareup.mockwebserver.version>3.10.0</squareup.mockwebserver.version>
        <sun.mail.version>1.6.2</sun.mail.version>
        <kie.kie-api.version>7.39.0.Final</kie.kie-api.version>
        <benefit_periods.version>1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</benefit_periods.version>
        <splunk.logging.version>1.6.0</splunk.logging.version>
        <qos.logback.version>0.1.5</qos.logback.version>
    </properties>    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.abc</groupId>
            <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
            <version>${abc.version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>${sun.mail.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.abc</groupId>
            <artifactId>abc-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${abc.abc-abc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${abc.abc-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>${abc.abc-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-workbench-models-guided-dtable</artifactId>
            <version>${abc.abc-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-bpmn2</artifactId>
            <version>${kie.kie-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbpm-flow-builder</artifactId>
            <version>${kie.kie-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.splunk.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>splunk-library-javalogging</artifactId>
            <version>${splunk.logging.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${qos.logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${qos.logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.json</groupId>
           <artifactId>json</artifactId>
           <version>20200518</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.abc.-----</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Below is the error that I am getting:

```
Cannot resolve com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1
Cannot resolve com.splunk.logging:splunk-library-javalogging:1.6.0
Cannot resolve com.abc:abc:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT
```

Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess this is related to  how you open the project. Do you select folder and press `Open` or you select POM.xml and select `Open`?

Comment: I selected the pom file while opening and opened it as a project. Below is the path I followed: File -> Open -> (select pom file from the path) -> Open as Project.

Comment: Did you downloaded all dependencies? Try running `mvn install` in the root directory using terminal or open `Maven tab` (to your right) and there will be an option to download dependencies and sources. Then close IntelliJ and reopen project.

Comment: @Reborn: I did that, but no luck! :(

Comment: What error do you get when trying to build from terminal: `mvn clean compile`?

Comment: `Cannot resolve com.abc:abc:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT` - looks like this is the dependency from one of your local projects? If so - it must be installed into your local Maven repository: it can be done using `mvn install` command for this `com.abc` Maven module.

Comment: I am getting the below error when i run mvn clean compile: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) on project abc: `Failed to clean project: Failed to delete
C:\Users\aaa\Documents\Code Reviews\abc\target\maven-status\maven-compiler-plugin\testCompile\default-testCompile -> [Help 1]`
[ERROR]
I also added the jar of `com.abc` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

go to the spring Initializr in chrome and click on maven and language java change groupid(package name) and artifactid(project name) and select on add dependencies button and search for dependies and add and then clock on generate after clicking on generate the zip file will be generated unzip it and import in intellij automatically dependencies will be injected to your maven spring boot project.
here is the spring initializr link "https://start.spring.io/".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have to change version of Java then clear and update the maven..